# Get the remaining days between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to calculate the remaining year, month and days between 2 dates using the method below, but I cannot get the remaining dates right. Is there a function or different method I should try?

```
Select (DATEDIFF(m, '1965-10-17', '2021-04-07')) /12 as AgeYr ,
       (DATEDIFF(m, '1965-10-17', '2021-04-07')) %12 as AgeMth,
       (DATEDIFF(d, '1965-10-17', '2021-04-07')) %30 as AgeDay;
```

This is the result of my code

| AgeYr | AgeMth | AgeDay |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 55 | 6 | 10 |

but the result should be

| AgeYr | AgeMth | AgeDay |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 55 | 6 | 21 |

Comment: This is actually not a well-defined problem -- is the difference between March 31 and Apr 30 "1 month" or "30 days"?  You need a lot more rules to explain what you really want.  But I don't recommend trying to do this.

Comment: yes the different between March 31 and Apr 30 would be "1 month"

Answer (score 1):

```
 DECLARE @date datetime, @startdate datetime, @enddate datetime, @years int, @months int, @days int
 SELECT @startdate = '1965-10-17'
 SELECT @enddate = '2021-04-07'
 
 
 SELECT @date = @startdate
 
 SELECT @years = DATEDIFF(yy, @startdate, @enddate) - CASE WHEN (MONTH(@date) > MONTH(@enddate)) OR (MONTH(@date) = MONTH(@enddate) AND DAY(@date) > DAY(@enddate)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
 SELECT @startdate = DATEADD(yy, @years, @startdate)
 SELECT @months = DATEDIFF(m, @startdate, @enddate) - CASE WHEN DAY(@date) > DAY(@enddate) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
 SELECT @startdate = DATEADD(m, @months, @startdate)
 SELECT @days = DATEDIFF(d, @startdate, @enddate)
 
 SELECT @years years, @months months, @days days
```

Output:

| AgeYr | AgeMth | AgeDay |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 55 | 5 | 21 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4fb2578839f8e8e6c9f967ed7560671c)*

You can also do it with common table expression:

```
 ;with years as
 (SELECT (DATEDIFF(yy, '1965-10-17', '2021-04-07') - CASE WHEN (MONTH('1965-10-17') > MONTH('2021-04-07')) OR (MONTH('1965-10-17') = MONTH('2021-04-07') AND DAY('1965-10-17') > DAY('2021-04-07')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AgeYr,
 '1965-10-17' startdate) 
 ,months as
 (SELECT (DATEDIFF(m, DATEADD(yy, years.AgeYr,  '1965-10-17'), '2021-04-07') - CASE WHEN DAY('1965-10-17') > DAY('2021-04-07') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AgeMth, DATEADD(yy, years.AgeYr, '1965-10-17') temp
 from years)
 ,days as 
 (select DATEDIFF(d, DATEADD(m, months.AgeMth, temp), '2021-04-07')AgeDay from months)
 select years.AgeYr,months.AgeMth,days.AgeDay from years,months,days
```

Output:

| AgeYr | AgeMth | AgeDay |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 55 | 5 | 21 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=587f9b810d97959daadad20f10d37940)*